# XmlArrayItem Deserialize to an empty List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm getting empty lists when I deserialize one of my List that has been concerted to XML.

I start out with my object GJurisdictions and serialize it to XML

```
<open511 xml:lang="en" xml:base="http://api.open511.info/" version="v0">
    <jurisdictions>
        <jurisdiction>
            <id>my.id</id>
            <languages>
                <language>en</language>
            </languages>
        </jurisdiction>
    </jurisdictions>
</open511>
```

This is exactly what I want but when I try to read it back in Languages is empty.

```
public class Jurisdiction 
{
        [XmlElement("id")]
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("languages")]
        [XmlArrayItem("language")]
        [JsonProperty("languages")]
        public List<String> Languages { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("open511")]
public class JurisdictionsBase : Open511Base
{
    private List<Jurisdiction> _jurisdictions;

    [XmlArray("jurisdictions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("jurisdiction")]
    [JsonProperty("jurisdiction")]
    public List<Jurisdiction> Jurisdictions
    {
        get { return _jurisdictions ?? (_jurisdictions = new List<Jurisdiction>()); }
        set { _jurisdictions = value; }
    }
}
```

The list of jurisdictions serializes perfectly and all the other properties (I edited for clarity) serialize perfectly but the language list is always empty, why?

Specification: http://open511.org/jurisdiction.html
Full Code: https://github.com/doublej42/Open511DotNet/blob/master/Open511DotNet/Jurisdiction.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't give enough information without reading the full source code. My problem was that somewhere else in my project I used some sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
{
    personName = reader.ReadString();
}
```

**Do not use the above code**
it doesn't move the reader ahead correctly.
As mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
   _unit = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```